# Fibonacci sequence using javascript, input 1st and 2nd number. Then I need to display the output on the webpage. Not console

Tags: javascript

Good day! I need some help.

I can't get the right loop for the fibonacci sequence. I need to input the first and second number, then add them to get the third number. To get the forth number I need to add the second and third. The problem is that the numbers are not adding, 0+1 should be 1 but it displays 01.

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fibonacci
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Enter first number: <input id="first" type="number"></p>
    <p>Enter second number: <input id="second" type="number"></p>
    <button onClick="fibonacci()">Submit</button>
    <p>Output: <p id="output"></p></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fibonacci(){
            num1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
            num2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
            next = 0;
            limit = 10;

            document.write(num1+', ');
            document.write(num2+', ');

            for(var i = 3; i <= limit; i++){
                next = num1 + num2;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = next;

                document.write(next+', ');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *0+1 should be 1 but it displays 01* without looking on your code this should be a string concatenation and not numbers adding, so you need to cast the string into number before adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the numbers are not adding, 0+1 should be 1 but it displays 01.

the reason is that the 0 and 1 are string not number. so u got 01

```js
next = Number(num1) + Number(num2)
```

Comment: A simple problem, but hard for me. Hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the variables to number type, add the + sign before num1 and num2

```js
for(var i = 3; i <= limit; i++){
                next = +num1 + +num2;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = next;

                document.write(next+', ');
            }
```

Comment: thanks!, im a native spanish speaker and i always have the same mistake